# Google Charts: On mouse hover bring selected chart to front

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-visualization

I am using google charts API to display multiple pie charts on the map. Since they are overlapping i want to add an interaction where hovering a mouse on a given piechart will bring it to top.

I tried using this code

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(this.chart, 'onmouseover', function(e) {
   this.chart.setZIndex(zIndex++);
        });
```

But i am not getting the correct response. Please let me know how can i bring the hovered chart to top.
Here is the related fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Vg6jm/

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a separate function which is called on mouseover:

```
click: function(event) {
            drawChart(marker, event);
            focusMarker(marker, event)
},
```

and

```
function focusMarker(marker, event) {
  $(marker.$div[0].parentNode).append(marker.$div[0]);
}
```

[JSfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Alessi42/Vg6jm/10/), I am unfamiliar with your way of setting event triggers so this will only be called on clicking on the chart but the function will set the selected chart div to be in front of the others.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Alessi 42.